# Spring+quartz giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/logging/LogEntryFormatter

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, quartz-scheduler

Im following http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/ to develop a job for my spring app... Im getting the following exception when im trying to run it.
Can anyone tell whats the resolution for this?

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/logging/LogEntryFormatter >
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:891)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at weblogic.logging.commons.LogImpl.<init>(LogImpl.java:14)
at weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:21)
at weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:18)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:70)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:59)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
at com.jobs.RunMeJob.main(RunMeJob.java:10)
```

Comment: Would you mind giving any code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the weblogic common logging mechanism in your app...and missing some jars/classes in your WL classpath. Can you post your classpath?
Also, you might want to try SLF4J for logging (http://www.slf4j.org) which I find so much easier to use (as well as versatile, allowing you to use any underlying logging mechanism, such as popular log4j for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed quartz to your Weblogic domain's lib directory you need to ensure that all of quartz dependencies are also deployed to the same directory.

I solved a similar problem by deploying `jcl-over-slf4j` and `slf4j-api`.